# Confusion about "$:=$" notation in pointwise convergence definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, soft-question, definition, pointwise-convergence

My instructor's lecture notes state:

> Let $\{f_n:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions defined on nonempty $E\subset\mathbb{R}$. We say that the sequence converges pointwisely to $f$ on $E$ if $\forall x\in E,\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n\geq N, |f_n(x)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon $. In this case, $f(x):=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$.

Why was $f$ defined in the last sentence? Doesn't the definition of pointwise convergence in the previous sentences imply that $f(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)$ for all $x\in E$ when pointwise convergence holds? I assumed that the notation "$:=$" is used to define $f$.

Comment: It is unusual. I think the intention is clearly to say "in that case, the notation $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ is defined to mean $f(x)$, so in the usual conventions it should say "$=:$", or the left-hand side and right-hand side should be switched. Perhaps it's a typo or your instructor prefers a nonstandard convention.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen: I think it would still be misleading to write $f(x)=:\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$. The RHS is just a limit of a *sequence of real numbers*, which already has a definition from introductory analysis. Really, the new notion that uniform convergence corresponds to is that of the limit of a *sequence of functions*. The notation that corresponds to this notion would be something like $f_n\to f$, or $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n=f$. It is only the last piece of notation that might deserve a $:=$ symbol if the writer so chooses.

Comment: @Joe, I suppose it is a little imprecise. But the notations $g(x)$ and $g$ are conflated all the time, even in pure maths. In this case $g$ would be $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$, which is a function we wish to define for each input $x$. This is done by stating that $g(x)$ is defined to be $f(x)$. That's the "good-faith" interpretation of this snippet that seems most reasonable to me. (or perhaps it's a quick redefinition of limit notation in the first place. Many courses I took started by re-defining all the basic concepts!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree; “$:=$” means “is defined to be”. It is used when introducing new notation. In this instance, the simple equality sign $=$ seems more appropriate.